# What is the GROK pattern for this log?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, grok

Can anyone please tell me the GROK pattern for this log

I am new to Logstash. Any help is appreciated

> : "ppsweb1 [ERROR] [JJN01234313887b4319ad0536bf6324j34h5469624340M] [913h56a5-e359-4a75-be9a-fae60d1a5ecb] 2016-07-28 13:14:58.848 [http-nio-8080-exec-4] PaymentAction - Net amount 149644"

Comment: what pattern did you try?

Comment: what output fields are you expecting?

Comment: I tried the standard log patterns, i.e. COMBINEDAPACHELOG , SYSLOGBASE

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
%{WORD:field1} \[%{LOGLEVEL:field2}\] \[%{NOTSPACE:field3}\] \[%{NOTSPACE:field4}\] %{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} \[%{NOTSPACE:field5}\] %{WORD:field6} - %{GREEDYDATA:field7} %{NUMBER:filed8}
```

And I got the output as:

```
{
  "field1": [
    [
      "ppsweb1"
    ]
  ],
  "field2": [
    [
      "ERROR"
    ]
  ],
  "field3": [
    [
      "JJN01234313887b4319ad0536bf6324j34h5469624340M"
    ]
  ],
  "field4": [
    [
      "913h56a5-e359-4a75-be9a-fae60d1a5ecb"
    ]
  ],
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "2016-07-28 13:14:58.848"
    ]
  ],
  "field5": [
    [
      "http-nio-8080-exec-4"
    ]
  ],
  "field6": [
    [
      "PaymentAction"
    ]
  ],
  "field7": [
    [
      "Net amount"
    ]
  ],
  "filed8": [
    [
      "149644"
    ]
  ]
}
```

You can change the names of fields as you want. You haven't mentioned anything about expected output in your question. So this is just to give you a basic idea. For further modifications you can use http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/ to verify your filter.

Note: I have used basic patterns, there are complex patterns available and you can play around with the debugger to suit your requirements.

Good luck!